# Every compact space is a continuous image of a compact Moscow space.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

From [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set),

> every compact metric space is a continuous image of the Cantor set.

and in [Topological Groups and Related Structures](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&source=bl&ots=fVNdS65_ud&sig=Fm0RqNKUht0Eh_vGx58MzVLtgz4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=75JJUcerKuiU0QXw1YDoDg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=every%20compact%20space%20is%20a%20continuous%20image%20of%20a%20moscow%20space&f=false) Ex 6.3.a.

> every compact space is a continuous image of a compact moscow space.

1. How can we show that every compact space is a continuous image of a compact moscow space?
2. Cantor set is a Moscow space?

Thanks.

---

A space $X$  is called *Moscow*, if for each open subset $U$ of $X$, the closure of $U$ in $X$ is the union of a family of $G‎_{δ}$‎‎‎  ‎-subsets of $X$ .

Comment: I did hear about Polish spaces, but never heard about a *Moscow* space. Interesting :)

Comment: In the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$ (and thus, in any subspace with the induced topology), a single point is a $G_\delta$ set. Therefore, any set is a union of a family of $G_\delta$ subsets (since any set is a union of all of its singleton subsets); in particular, any subset is Moscow. However, not every compact space is *metric* so this isn't enough to get your second conclusion.

Comment: Somewhat more general than @YoniRozenshein's comment: in a first-countable Hausdorff (even T$_1$) space all singletons are G$_\delta$, and thus all subsets are unions of G$_\delta$ sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to answer your questions:

1. A space is said to be [extremely disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) if the closure of every open set is open. Extremely disconnected spaces are Moscow spaces. The Čech-Stone compactification $\beta D$ of a discrete space $D$ is extremely disconnected and hence a compact Moscow space. Now let $X$ be compact and let $X_\delta$ be the set $X$ endowed with the discrete topology. Then the identity mapping $X_\delta \to X$ is continuous and surjective and by the universal property of the Čech-Stone compactification it extends to a continuous and surjective function $\beta X_\delta \to X$. This shows that every compact space $X$ is (canonically) the continuous image of a compact Moscow space.
2. As an alternative to the arguments suggested in the comments, observe that in a metric space closed sets are $G_\delta$-sets, so the closure of an open set is a $G_\delta$-set and hence metric spaces are Moscow spaces. Since the Cantor set is a metric space, it is a Moscow space.